# Saving as a string from FireStore Flutter Firebase Database

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to take one of the current User's label from my FireStore Database, and save it as a string. I have already figured out how to find the currentUserID, so that isn't the problem. I just can't figure out how to target the "preference" label in my database:

```
String _checkPreference(DocumentSnapshot document) {
  Firestore.instance.collection(currentUserId).document('preference').toString();

  return _checkPreference(document);
  }
```

The goal is then later to be able to do something like this:

```
  return Text(_checkPreference(document));
```

Bit I am not really sure what to pass in or if my method is correct. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By calling `.document('preference')`, you actually do only get the reference of the document.

The thing you might want to do is :

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = await Firestore
    .instance
    .collection(currentUserId)
    .document('preference')
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot snap) => snap.data);
return /*the data you need to get*/
```

That way you will get what is contained **inside** the document, and be able to get the data you want to display from the `Map`.

Comment: Okay I think this will work, but I am not really sure what to return?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Jonathan did you see my comment?

Comment: The document named ‘preference’ has a value you want to display if I understand right. So the return would be `data[“THE KEY OF THE VALUE YOU WANT TO DISPLAY”]`